# How to downgrade Visual Studio Code to 0.9.1

Tags: visual-studio-code, downgrade

Since the 0.10.1 Visual Studio Code upgrade my Macbook Air makes a lot of 
sound, from the fan. Can I downgrade or are there any new things I can disable to make it run better?

Answer (score -2):

If you are not happy with VS Code 0.10, please file bugs at our GitHub repository: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: previous releases link is broken

Comment: looks like we no longer advertise older releases

Comment: yes you do, I just found it at https://code.visualstudio.com/updates